# Is there a way to wait the last command to GPU before next command?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have the following code in the display: (it's the whole display func, and the data changes in the idle func)

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawPixels(100,100,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,data);
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
```

And when I compiled this code, sometimes it flashes the same color as the background.
I think that the GPU catches the drawpixel before the clear color, and it clears the buffer.

I could delay between the clear and the draw, but I change `data` almost between every frame.
What should I do?
Is there a flush like command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you forgot to specify GLUT_DOUBLE in your `glutInitDisplayMode()` call, and were thus given a non-double-buffered context.

Also, it's not customary to include a `glutPostRedisplay()` within your display function--that should be at the end of your idle function instead.